# How can I loop through a select, call a stored procedure and process the results?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a select:

```
SELECT AnswerGridResponses,
       QuestionUId, 
       UserTestQuestionId
FROM   UserTest,
       UserTestQuestion
WHERE  UserTest.UserTestId = @UserTestId
AND    UserTest.UserTestId = UserTestQuestion.UserTestId
```

and a procedure I need to call:

```
EXEC sp_get_correct_responses @QuestionUId, @AnswerGridCorrect output
```

Can someone give an example of how inside a stored procedure I can call the stored procedure and pass in the @QuestionUId. I have more processing I need to do after it's passed in but I think if I know how to loop then that will give me all I need.

Comment: You shouldn't JOIN tables via the WHERE clause. That style was deprecated as of SQL Server 2005. Please use `FROM tableA INNER JOIN tableB ON tableB.KeyField = tableA.KeyField WHERE...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Cursor` to do this.

```
  DECLARE CUR CURSOR STATIC FOR
  SELECT DISTINCT QuestionUId
  FROM   UserTest 
  INNER JOIN  UserTestQuestion
  ON UserTest.UserTestId = UserTestQuestion.UserTestId
  WHERE  UserTest.UserTestId = @UserTestId


OPEN vendor_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @QuestionUId

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
      EXEC Sp_get_correct_responses
        @QuestionUId,
        @AnswerGridCorrect output

      FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @QuestionUId
  END

CLOSE CUR;

DEALLOCATE CUR;
```

**Note :** Cursor may lead to poor performance. Try changing the RBAR operation to set based approach

Comment: You should probably add the cursor option `STATIC` to the `DECLARE`. Also wouldn't hurt to correct the deprecated join syntax :)

Comment: Looks good. Just to be clear, I was recommending the `STATIC` option to reduce contention on systems that do not have Read Committed Snapshot Islation enabled. +1